# sql query - table@string meaning

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to understand a query . When I run the below query , no rows are fetched.

```
select * from Table
```

But when I run the query , a result is returned having multiple rows.

```
select * from Table@somestring
```

I am not sure what *@* followed by *somestring* means and why that is used in PL/SQL.

Comment: Does It return any Output? I yes then is it same as first Query's output?

Comment: Mate , the first query fethes no result. But the second query returns 4 rows.

Comment: I worked on it 1 year before, I am guessing **Table** before @ is a **username** and **somestring** is your **tablename**. You can view username from PLSQL window in lefthand side panel in Users folder.

Comment: Table is definitely a table. Have checked the same in the database. Not sure about somestring though

Comment: Not sure why this is being marked as off-topic. *Managing* database links can be a DBA taks, but knowing what they are and how to use them is a programming topic. (This isn't PL/SQL-specific though, DB links are used in plain Oracle SQL too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of a [distributed query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries010.htm). The string after the `@` is a [database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements009.htm#i27761).

You can see where the database link is pointing by querying the [`all_db_links` view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_1066.htm), or the `user_` or `dba_` equivalents depending on the owner and your privileges. It might refer to a TNS alias, in which case you could get further details from the `tnsnames.ora` file.

When you query `table` you're (usually) looking at a table in your own schema. When you query `table@dblink` you're looking at a table in a remote database. They are different objects so you'd expect different results. Your local table is empty, but the remote one has some data.

I say 'usually' because `table` *could* be a synonym pointing at another schema, or even to a schema on a remote database itself. And `dblink` *could* be pointing back to your own database - it would be unusual but I've seen it done as a way of accessing another schema (not something I'd recommend). Without seeing if there is a synonym or where the `dblink` is going it's hard to be definitive, but these are less common scenarios. In this case though you're clearly hitting two different tables, probably on different databases. (Well, unless there's a VPD and connecting to the same table as a different user gives a different view... but starting to go down the rabbit hole now...)

Comment: This info was very helpful :) Thanks for taking the time to explain .